# php rewriteEngine using .htaccess not showing css

Tags: php, css, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I use .htaccess to rewrite urls. See the example below :

my folder arborescence is like that :

- mysite (folder)

  - css (folder)

    - style.css
  - mypage.php
  - .htaccess

when i call `http://localhost/mysite/mypage/myid` it is redirected to `http://localhost/mysite/mypage.php?id=myid`

The problem then is that it doesn't seem to call my css which is :

```
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

The content of my .htaccess is :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /mysite
RewriteRule ^mypage/([^/]*) mypage.php?id=$1
```

Thanks in advance

**Edit :**

I tryied with the solution :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

I still cannot get the css called :/

**Edit 2 :**

Ok i could get it work calling my css like this :

```
<link href="/mysite/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Looks like i also have to call all my images i have in the html using the path "/mysite/"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your styling get's called relative now, so you should call it absolute.

There is no /myid/css/ folder, that's what your code is looking for now.

```
<link href="<?php echo $_SERVER['SCRIPT_URI'];?>css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: Is the result of that function supposed to write <link href="http://localhost/mysite/css/style.css"> ? Because i get php error using that function (im on windows Wamp srv). Thank you

Comment: Yes, on a live server, it will echo the complete uri of the current page. But because you are running on localhost, it doesnt work somehow. it should say 
    (http://)localhost/mysite/css/style.css.

Comment: ok, so i also have to add this function for all the <img src=""> right ? Isnt there an other way to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

add a rewritecondition:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^mypage/([^/]*) mypage.php?id=$1
```

now your css (and other files and directories) will not be sent trough the rewriterule

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell the rewrite engine to ignore directories and files that actually exist:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /mysite
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^mypage/([^/]*) mypage.php?id=$1
```